# check the date format that is it correct or not

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, date-format, php-carbon

i want to check the date format of the database value. I want to put a check in my code if the format of the date string is correct. If it is not correct then store the empty value.

```
$getTmpAfSite =   DB::table('tmp_af_site')->orderBy('id','DESC')->get(['id','name','email','number','origin','destination','estimated_rate','make','model','year','running_condition','carrier_type','avail_date','lead_source','request_params','bats_id','submitted_on']);
                    
                    foreach ($getTmpAfSite as $key => $value) {
                       
                        $avail_date = ($value->avail_date != '' && $value->avail_date == Carbon::parse($value->submitted_on)->format('m/d/Y')) ? Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $value->avail_date)->format('Y-m-d') : '0000-00-00';
                        $submitted_on = ($value->submitted_on != '' && $value->submitted_on == Carbon::parse($value->submitted_on)->format('m/d/Y H:i')) ? Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y H:i', $value->submitted_on)->format('Y-m-d H:i') : '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
                        DB::table('tmp_af_site')->where('id', $value->id)->update([
                            'avail_date'=>$avail_date,
                            'submitted_on'=>$submitted_on
                        ]);
                    }
```

i am trying this code to check the value but its not working for me. If i didn't put a check on it and the wrong format comes then the error happens. ***Here is the error***
[Unexpected data found. Data missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcDb6.png)

Comment: You can use try {} catch {} to catch the Unexpected data found exception when you parse()

Comment: Please provide your error message as text, not as a screenshot.  You can copy and paste it.

Answer (score 2):

try use this function, this function check valid or not valid string date with return true false

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'd-M-Y')
{
  $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
  return $d && $d->format($format) === $date;
}
```

if you want more format date, you can add checking date like this

```
function validateDate($date)
{
  $valid = 0;
  $format1 = 'Y-m-d';
  $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format1, $date);
  if($d && $d->format($format) === $date){
    $valid = 1;
  }
  $format2 = 'd-m-Y';
  $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format2, $date);
  if($d && $d->format($format2) === $date){
    $valid = 1;
  }
  return $valid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
checkdate(int $month, int $day, int $year): bool
```

Example :

```
<?php
var_dump(checkdate(12, 31, 2000));
var_dump(checkdate(2, 29, 2001));

#bool(true)
#bool(false)

$valid = checkdate(12,31,2000);

if ($valid)
    echo "Date is valid.";
else
    echo "Date is not valid.";

?>
```

Regards,